# Error importing TensorFlow GPU in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to import TensorFlow but end up with this error.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/Aakaash/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>()
     60     sys.setdlopenflags(_default_dlopen_flags | ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
---> 61     from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     62     sys.setdlopenflags(_default_dlopen_flags)

/Users/Aakaash/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

/Users/Aakaash/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

/Users/Aakaash/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    241         else:
--> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

/Users/Aakaash/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 342         return _load(spec)
    343 

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Aakaash/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Aakaash/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Reason: image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-a649b509054f> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow

/Users/Aakaash/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>()
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import *
     25 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
     26 

/Users/Aakaash/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>()
     70 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     71 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 72   raise ImportError(msg)
     73 
     74 # Protocol buffers

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Aakaash/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Users/Aakaash/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/Aakaash/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Users/Aakaash/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Users/Aakaash/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Aakaash/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Aakaash/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Reason: image not found


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I am able to import the CPU Version of the TensorFlow with no issue. I am also able to import TensorFlow in Python Console launched from Terminal. The path to python executable is same in both Console and Jupyter Notebook (`sys.executable` gave same output in Console and Jupyter Notebook).

TensorFlow version - 1.0.0

Python Version - 3.5.2

Cuda Version - 8.0

Comment: This seems like an install problem, that we track on our github issue page. Please file an issue there. The root problem is that your environment is unable to locate the cuda library. Please set up the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` appropriately. You can run `ldd` on the `_pywrap_tensorflow.so` object to check if you have gotten it right.

Comment: Alright. I will file an issue on Github. Can you please tell me how to setup the LD_LIBRARY_PATH properly? I am new to this and I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: Please follow the [install guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux). It has a pointer to the NVIDIA documentation.

Comment: Thank you. I will follow it.

Comment: to add to this, I have the tensorflow gpu working correctly in a python console launched from terminal. So I think my install is fine.  But inside Jupiter I get an error as well.  And I am on ubuntu.

Comment: @user798719 Did you try the solution below? That worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the error was when I setup CUDA and CuDNN. Following the guide provided by Nvidia, it told me to setup the path for `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` for Mac OS X. Unfortunately, this does not work when using Jupyter Notebook. We need to follow the steps the Nvidia's guide has for Linux and setup the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when starting Jupyter notebook the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was cleared even if exported it in `.bashrc` and `.profile` on Ubuntu. Only starting the notebook server with `env VARIABLE=$VARIABLE jupyter notebook` solved it.